# Remove all blue nodes from the tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Given a binary tree with nodes having color attribute. The tree has red nodes and blue nodes.

Remove all blue nodes from the tree and return a tree with only the red nodes?

I have tried to implement this like this:

```
Node stripblue(Node root)
{
    if(root.left != NULL)
      root.left = stripblue(root.left) //is this line correct ? //TODO

    if(root.right != NULL)
       root.right = stripblue(root.right) // is this line correct ? //TODO

     if(root.color == RED)
     return root
}
```

I am having some trouble wrapping my head on implementing the `TODO` part of my algorithm. Can someone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there are no restrictions on the traversal order before deletion and after, I write one, which looks like the deletion of a common binary tree's node.

```
Node stripblue(Node root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if(root.color == BLUE)
    {
        Node next_r;
        next_r = search_red(root.left);
        if(next_r == NULL)
            next_r = search_red(root.right);
                if(next_r == NULL)
                    return NULL;
                    //no node is RED

            //TODO:swap the content of next_r and root
            next_r.color = BLUE;
            root.color = RED;
    }
    root.left  = stripblue(root.left);
    root.right = stripblue(root.right);
    return root;
}
```

while `search_red(Node root)` is a function to find the first RED node below the root.If you want to keep the RED nodes' order the same before and after in preorder traversal,your `search_red(Node root)` is to find the first node in preorder of the left-child, or the first node of the right-child.

Comment: So you return a sub tree finally using in place swaps from top down ? Cool I was returning a new tree

Comment: @user1701868 (a complex way,for reference only) if you want a new tree, you can do a preorder traversal  and a inorder traversal which only record the RED node. By the two sequences, you can rebulid a new tree with only RED ones.

Comment: @user1701868 if your original tree is all nodes RED and at least depth of 3, your function will remove the nodes such as root, the root.right, the root.left, the root.left.left and so on. I don't think its a good solution for removal all BLUE nodes bucause it removes lots of RED nodes at the same time...

Comment: Consider this case my node has a red left leaf then clearly it simply returns the red leaf and terminates. I made a mistake , can you somehow edit my algorithm to make it work ? I just want it for my understanding

Comment: @user1701868 it's about the restrictions and implements. The big problem is when the root is BLUE,how to deal with it.You can change the implement of `search_red(Node root)` according to your need. Thus I think my solution is just one of implements of your code's frame.